# Ubuntu 23.10 installer won't start

Tags: system-installation

The system boots in live mode, and then the installer crashes and crashes every time it starts.

Here are my logs.

ubuntu_desktop_installer.log:

```
2023-10-14 10:52:43.565179 INFO subiquity_server: Waiting server up to 90 seconds
2023-10-14 10:52:43.566877 ERROR subiquity_server: SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2), address = /run/subiquity/socket, port = 0
```

subiquity-server-debug.log: https://hastebin.com/share/orunugumig.yaml

`tail` of subiquity-server-debug.log

```
storage:
-   id: disk-sdb
    path: /dev/sdb
    ptable: dos
    serial: Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_070391BC249E7421-0:0
    type: disk
-   id: disk-sda
    path: /dev/sda
    ptable: dos
    serial: SATA_SSD_128GB_YT20220504847
    type: disk
-   device: disk-sdb
    flag: boot
    id: partition-sdb1
    number: 1
    offset: 1048576
    partition_type: '0xc'
    path: /dev/sdb1
    size: 30971789312
    type: partition
-   device: disk-sda
    flag: boot
    id: partition-sda1
    number: 1
    offset: 1048576
    partition_type: '0x7'
    path: /dev/sda1
    size: 524288000
    type: partition
-   device: disk-sda
    id: partition-sda2
    number: 2
    offset: 525336576
    partition_type: '0x7'
    path: /dev/sda2
    size: 66584576000
    type: partition
-   device: disk-sda
    flag: linux
    id: partition-sda3
    number: 3
    offset: 67110961152
    partition_type: '0x83'
    path: /dev/sda3
    size: 60924362752
    type: partition
-   fstype: vfat
    id: format-partition-sdb1
    type: format
    volume: partition-sdb1
-   fstype: ntfs
    id: format-partition-sda1
    type: format
    volume: partition-sda1
-   fstype: vfat
    id: format-partition-sda2
    type: format
    volume: partition-sda2
-   fstype: ext4
    id: format-partition-sda3
    type: format
    uuid: 6d18ae7d-63f5-4770-a495-92a24a344604
    volume: partition-sda3
-   device: format-partition-sdb1
    id: mount-partition-sdb1
    path: /cdrom
    type: mount

2023-10-14 10:53:05,957 DEBUG curtin:1359 Generating storage config dependencies
2023-10-14 10:53:05,958 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: partition-sdb1:SourceType:partition -> (DepId:disk-sdb DepType:disk) in SourceDeps:{'disk', 'partition', 'bcache', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,958 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: partition-sda1:SourceType:partition -> (DepId:disk-sda DepType:disk) in SourceDeps:{'disk', 'partition', 'bcache', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,958 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: partition-sda2:SourceType:partition -> (DepId:disk-sda DepType:disk) in SourceDeps:{'disk', 'partition', 'bcache', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,958 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: partition-sda3:SourceType:partition -> (DepId:disk-sda DepType:disk) in SourceDeps:{'disk', 'partition', 'bcache', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,958 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: format-partition-sdb1:SourceType:format -> (DepId:partition-sdb1 DepType:partition) in SourceDeps:{'dm_crypt', 'bcache', 'disk', 'lvm_partition', 'partition', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,958 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: partition-sdb1:SourceType:partition -> (DepId:disk-sdb DepType:disk) in SourceDeps:{'disk', 'partition', 'bcache', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,958 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: format-partition-sda1:SourceType:format -> (DepId:partition-sda1 DepType:partition) in SourceDeps:{'dm_crypt', 'bcache', 'disk', 'lvm_partition', 'partition', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,959 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: partition-sda1:SourceType:partition -> (DepId:disk-sda DepType:disk) in SourceDeps:{'disk', 'partition', 'bcache', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,959 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: format-partition-sda2:SourceType:format -> (DepId:partition-sda2 DepType:partition) in SourceDeps:{'dm_crypt', 'bcache', 'disk', 'lvm_partition', 'partition', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,959 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: partition-sda2:SourceType:partition -> (DepId:disk-sda DepType:disk) in SourceDeps:{'disk', 'partition', 'bcache', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,959 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: format-partition-sda3:SourceType:format -> (DepId:partition-sda3 DepType:partition) in SourceDeps:{'dm_crypt', 'bcache', 'disk', 'lvm_partition', 'partition', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,959 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: partition-sda3:SourceType:partition -> (DepId:disk-sda DepType:disk) in SourceDeps:{'disk', 'partition', 'bcache', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,959 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: mount-partition-sdb1:SourceType:mount -> (DepId:format-partition-sdb1 DepType:format) in SourceDeps:{'format'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,960 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: format-partition-sdb1:SourceType:format -> (DepId:partition-sdb1 DepType:partition) in SourceDeps:{'dm_crypt', 'bcache', 'disk', 'lvm_partition', 'partition', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,960 DEBUG curtin:236 Validate: partition-sdb1:SourceType:partition -> (DepId:disk-sdb DepType:disk) in SourceDeps:{'disk', 'partition', 'bcache', 'raid'} ? result=True
2023-10-14 10:53:05,960 DEBUG curtin:1365 Merging storage config dependencies
2023-10-14 10:53:05,969 DEBUG curtin:1370 Merged storage config:
storage:
    config:
    -   id: disk-sda
        path: /dev/sda
        ptable: dos
        serial: SATA_SSD_128GB_YT20220504847
        type: disk
    -   id: disk-sdb
        path: /dev/sdb
        ptable: dos
        serial: Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_070391BC249E7421-0:0
        type: disk
    -   device: disk-sdb
        flag: boot
        id: partition-sdb1
        number: 1
        offset: 1048576
        partition_type: '0xc'
        path: /dev/sdb1
        size: 30971789312
        type: partition
    -   fstype: vfat
        id: format-partition-sdb1
        type: format
        volume: partition-sdb1
    -   device: format-partition-sdb1
        id: mount-partition-sdb1
        path: /cdrom
        type: mount
    -   device: disk-sda
        flag: boot
        id: partition-sda1
        number: 1
        offset: 1048576
        partition_type: '0x7'
        path: /dev/sda1
        size: 524288000
        type: partition
    -   device: disk-sda
        id: partition-sda2
        number: 2
        offset: 525336576
        partition_type: '0x7'
        path: /dev/sda2
        size: 66584576000
        type: partition
    -   device: disk-sda
        flag: linux
        id: partition-sda3
        number: 3
        offset: 67110961152
        partition_type: '0x83'
        path: /dev/sda3
        size: 60924362752
        type: partition
    -   fstype: ntfs
        id: format-partition-sda1
        type: format
        volume: partition-sda1
    -   fstype: vfat
        id: format-partition-sda2
        type: format
        volume: partition-sda2
    -   fstype: ext4
        id: format-partition-sda3
        type: format
        uuid: 6d18ae7d-63f5-4770-a495-92a24a344604
        volume: partition-sda3
    version: 2

2023-10-14 10:53:05,970 DEBUG subiquity.models.filesystem:1406 exclusions {'partition-sdb1', 'format-partition-sdb1', 'disk-sdb'}
2023-10-14 10:53:05,970 DEBUG root:37 finish: subiquity/Filesystem/_probe/probe_once: SUCCESS: restricted=False
2023-10-14 10:53:05,971 DEBUG root:37 finish: subiquity/SnapList/loader/fetch/google-cloud-sdk: SUCCESS: 
2023-10-14 10:53:05,971 DEBUG subiquity.server.controllers.filesystem:866 block probing took 5.0 seconds
2023-10-14 10:53:05,971 DEBUG root:37 finish: subiquity/Filesystem/_probe: SUCCESS: 
2023-10-14 10:53:05,972 DEBUG root:37 start: subiquity/SnapList/loader/fetch/slcli:
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu 23.10 product are you using?  Your details above mention `subiquity_server` which is used by two installers on two different products (Server & Desktop), where as I noted `ubuntu-desktop-installer` which currently is still in *testing* and technically *unreleased* which implies Desktop.  Please be specific with details; and note the Desktop ISOs using `ubuntu-desktop-installer` are not yet fully released.

Comment: I'm using Desktop, I downloaded it on the 12th and now this version is no longer available for download https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/announcement-ubuntu-desktop-23-10-release-image-is-being-updated-to-resolve-a-malicious-translation-incident/39365

Comment: The ISO in your last comment uses the `ubiquity` installer, yet your messages show `subiquity` which is from an different ISO, please clarify your facts.

Comment: The *corrected* ISO that is currently being tested can be found at https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/20231013/mantic-desktop-amd64.iso which has both the *offensive language* issue fixed, plus some other issues also fixed (*though I've not verified this & its based on a comment I read*) so your details show you using an *unsupported* ISO.  The ISO link I use here is an RC or *release-candidate* only, it'll only become the official ISO if all testing completes successfully.

Comment: The installation worked, but gave an error during the process. A bug report has already been sent, I’d better install version 22

Comment: I also had issues in my case it just reaches `Started gdm.service` and then the screen starts flickering. Also in the beginning it prints: `Nuveau unknown chipset`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with the default installer for Ubuntu 23.10, try the Legacy Desktop Installer available on the same [Download Ubuntu Desktop](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) page.

Your question and this answer are time sensitive, and the situation is likely to change as the new installer is improved. As of now, I also ran into problems with the new installer, trying many times with different combinations (online, offline, with and without 3rd party software, default installation mode or defining partitions...) and having to restart a dozen times because of its unreliability.

I was going to download the Ubuntu 23.10 image again hoping that it would contain a bugfix when I realized that there is a link to the legacy installer version. I downloaded that version instead and the installation process was flawless, as it has been for the most part in Ubuntu's history.